# All fans in PC run except one case fan, PC turns on and off in a loop

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I have 3 case fans, 2 of which are connected to the psu while the third is connected to the CPU_FAN on the motherboard. All of the fans plus CPU and GPU fans run fine except for the third case fan. The PC turns on and off in a loop, which doesn't make sense since it ran fine in the past on the same connections. I also replaced the old PSU in my PC, but nothing changed. I don't hear any BIOS beeps, no motherboard lights, and the display doesn't work either.

Here are the specs:

- Windows 11 Home OS
- Asrock B450 Pro4 motherboard
- GTX 970 GPU
- Ryzen 5 3600 CPU
- WD 500 GB
- 8 GB RAM
- EVGA 750W PSU
- 2 case fans are sata connection fans while the third is the fan the case came with, 3 pin cable

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146435/discussion-on-question-by-amateur-pc-user-all-fans-in-pc-run-except-one-case-fan); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.